LaTeX modules in Ubuntu packages
Ubuntu distributes several LaTeX-related packages which allow to not do full install and gradually grow the local installation of TexLive.
For example, there exist:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/texlive-latex-base/filelist
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/texlive-latex-recommended/filelist
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/texlive-science/filelist
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/texlive-fonts-recommended/filelist

Does anybody know how are these built and where to find any build script sources for them? I would like to replicate them with a profile file for install-tl or build a profile based on composing several of these packages.
Thanks!

wouldn't it be better to ask this on an ubuntu site?

Since disk space is cheap, I've found it much easier to just install a full TeXLive (2024 or whatever) rather than utilizing myriad distro packages which attempt to control disk usage. You then have everything with zero issues.

Ubuntu uses repackages TeX Live from Debian, who repackage code packaged by TeX Live, which packages code from CTAN.
It is remarkable how difficult Canonical make it to find source code for the software they publish. I'm sure it is there, it is just striking how very well-hidden it is.
In any case, given they follow Debian and Debian take as much trouble with transparency as Canonical apparently take with obscurity, I would just look there. It is probably where you will end up if you start from Ubuntu source anyway.
https://sources.debian.org/search/texlive/ seems a reasonable starting point. I suggest looking at the 2024 version if you are thinking of using this as a profile for a TeX Live install from upstream, since that will be using the same infrastructure as current TeX Live.
For example, texlive-extra contains the sources for texlive-extra, including the files Debian uses to modify them and create packages.
Note that pretty much all Linux distros seem to split TeX Live into packages and they all modify TeX Live to some extent, though some make more drastic changes than others.
I'm not entirely clear why you want details of this process if the aim is to create a profile to install TeX Live. In that case, the package lists you already have are likely the key thing. Much of the packaging process is a matter of adapting the source to work with the distro's package manager and directory layout, which isn't relevant if you just want to create a profile to use with upstream's install script.
Edit
You can find texlive-fonts-recommended as one of the packages produced by the build of texlive-base.
https://sources.debian.org/src/texlive-extra/2024.20241115-1/debian/cfg.d/package-naming.cfg/ includes
#
# collections -> debian package names plus source packages
#
# texlive-base
...
name;collection-fontsrecommended;texlive-fonts-recommended;texlive-base
...

https://sources.debian.org/src/texlive-extra/2024.20241115-1/debian/cfg.d/font-ignore.cfg/ shows which font files in texlive-extra get replaced by dependencies.
https://sources.debian.org/src/texlive-extra/2024.20241115-1/debian/tpm2deb.cfg/ includes the .deb package configuration for texlive-fonts-recommended and other packages in texlive-extra. https://sources.debian.org/src/texlive-extra/2024.20241115-1/debian/tpm2deb-bin.pl/ is the script which uses that configuration. https://sources.debian.org/src/texlive-extra/2024.20241115-1/debian/tpm2debcommon.pm/ provides methods used by that script.

I was wondering if I can claw out somewhere something like a LaTeX package list or even a pre-cooked profile file without having to work backwards form the file list... And was hoping that it exists somewhere and the culprit is just knowing the obscure URL or gitlab page :)
In particular, I am interested in how to obtain something like https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/all/texlive-fonts-recommended/filelist with a install-tl profile file and knowing which packages I need to add to end up with this font list

Seems that https://sources.debian.org/src/texlive-fonts-recommended/ does not exist. So it must be some Ubuntu's specialty :(

@VadimKantorov see edit for texlive-fonts-recommended. it is just part of texlive-extra, which is not a single package but a group of packages, which are all built together. pretty much all distros provide some version of texlive-fonts-recommended - it is just a repackaged version of upstream's similarly named grouping. if you just want to install that, you can just use upstream's installer and select the relevant options.
